# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file. File name: 'System.Net.Sockets.resources'

Tags: c#, angular, webpack

I am developing a dotnet core application with Angular.

I am trying to migrate to dotnet core 2.1 and Angular 6.

I was able to migrate first to dotnet core 2.1 with no problems, but when I tried to migrate to the latest Angular build I encountered problems.

It is not the problem with Angular itself, but with webpack. I upgraded all the packages in package.json (with the exception of webpack ones) to the latest versions with no problem, but HMR was not working and I was not able to run

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

either.

So, I used

```
npm install npm-check-updates -g
ncu -u
npm install
```

to upgrade webpack also.

I now have this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "SIGAD",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=1600 app.js < /dev/null",
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-cool/storage": "^1.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.7",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^3.1.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^6.0.16",
    "ng2-datepicker-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
    "css": "^2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.16",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "preboot": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.18.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  }
}
```

The problem is I get internal server error when I try to start my application. With debug I catch this exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
File name: 'System.Net.Sockets.resources'
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingEvent(AssemblyName assemblyName)
```

I did no changes to my C# code. I upgraded all dependencies after I migrated to dotnet core 2.1 with no problem.

My Startup.cs is:

```
namespace SIGAD
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static string databaseConnection = "";
        private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH"; // todo: get this from somewhere secure
        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Configuration = config;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            try {

                services.AddAutoMapper();

                databaseConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                if (databaseConnection == null) databaseConnection = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SIGADCORE;Trusted_Connection=true";

                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(databaseConnection));

                DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = databaseConnection;

                services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

                // jwt wire up
                // Get options from app settings
                var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

                // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
                services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                    options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
                    options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                });

                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
                });

                // Add application services.
                services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
                services.AddNodeServices();

                services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

                services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                });

                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                AddErrorToDatabase(e);
            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            try {

                loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggerFactory.AddDebug();

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                    {
                        HotModuleReplacement = true,
                        HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseDefaultFiles();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseCookiePolicy();

                var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
                var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };

                app.UseAuthentication();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                        name: "spa-fallback",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });


                CreateRoles(serviceProvider);

                if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en-US")
                    SessionConstants.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ro-RO");
                else
                    SessionConstants.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ro-RO");

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = SessionConstants.CultureInfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = SessionConstants.CultureInfo;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                AddErrorToDatabase(e);
            }
        }

        private void CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            Task<IdentityResult> roleResult;

            string[] roleNames = { RoleNames.Admin, RoleNames.Supraveghetor, RoleNames.Operator, RoleNames.OperatorCuModificare, RoleNames.OperatorCuVizualizare };

            //Check that there is an Administrator role and create if not

            foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                Task<bool> hasAdminRole = roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
                hasAdminRole.Wait();
                if (!hasAdminRole.Result)
                {
                    roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                    roleResult.Wait();
                }
            }

        }

        public static void AddErrorToDatabase(Exception e)
        {
            // Get stack trace for the exception with source file information
            var st = new StackTrace(e, true);
            // Get the stack frames

            string file = "";
            string fileTemp = "";
            string method = "";
            string lineNumber = "";

            foreach (StackFrame frame in st.GetFrames())
            {
                // Get the file name from the stack frame
                fileTemp = frame.GetFileName() ?? "";
                fileTemp = fileTemp.Replace('\\', '-').Split('-').Last().Trim();

                int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

                if (line > 0)
                {
                    file += "-> " + fileTemp + "\n";

                    // Get the method from the stack frame
                    method = "-> " + frame.GetMethod().ToString().Substring(frame.GetMethod().ToString().IndexOf(' '), frame.GetMethod().ToString().IndexOf('(') - frame.GetMethod().ToString().IndexOf(' ')) + "\n";

                    // Get the line number from the stack frame
                    lineNumber += "-> " + frame.GetFileLineNumber().ToString() + "\n";
                }
            }

            string destails = e.Message;

            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                var innerException = e;

                Exception realerror = e;
                while (realerror.InnerException != null)
                {
                    realerror = realerror.InnerException;
                    destails += "\n" + realerror.Message;
                }
            }

            if (databaseConnection != null)
            {
                string QueryString = "INSERT INTO Error(Description,Moment,[File],Method,Line) VALUES (@description,@moment,@file,@method,@line)";

                System.Type tipProdus = e.GetType();

                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(databaseConnection);
                SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, myConnection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // add the elements to the list
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(databaseConnection))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", destails);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moment", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", file);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@method", method);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line", lineNumber);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //string folderPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string path = "errors" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".txt";
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    // Create a file to write to.
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(destails);
                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                        sw.WriteLine(file);
                        sw.WriteLine(method);
                        sw.WriteLine(lineNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

There was no error, but the changes where not being reflected in the app. I tried running

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

but now I was getting the error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\Bosch.SIGAD-Core\SIGAD\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
```

so I installed it with

```
npm install popper.js -D
```

ran

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

again and it worked, but now I am getting this error.

I don't even know where to start investigating this error. Any ideas would be great.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

if I commnet:

```
 app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
    {
       HotModuleReplacement = true,
        HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
 });
```

in Startup.cs, I don't get internal server error, but I get

```
Uncaught Error: Type e is part of the declarations of 2 modules: e and e! Please consider moving e to a higher module that imports e and e. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes e then import that NgModule in e and e.
```

in browser console...

UPDATE 2:

I want to emphasize that even if I create a new project with dotnet core and Angular, after I

`npm install npm-check-updates -g
ncu -u
npm install`

I get this error and I am not able to start my app

I have found this:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/14482

which seems to be the escat same problem, but I do not see any solution there.

Comment: the things becomes easer. You can forget about webpack. use the new Template Angular of .NET Core 2.1 and create a angular 6 application using angular-cli in ClientApp folder. all work like silk. I say you are using an old template because I can see in your stratup.cs dome like useClientApp: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio. Tip: Some time it's better begins with a basic example and the add the differents services and services configuration

Comment: I actually did create a new Angular project last week with Visual Studio and it didn't work either. The project starts with Angular 5.2 and if I try to migrate, it stops working also.

Comment: Andrei, the project has Angular 5.2. Remove ClientApp folder and write ng new ClientApp in your project folder. Must be work

Comment: NICE! that did work, but my project is huge. I started working on it since there was only Angular 2. Migrating the files will take a lot. How can I speed that?

Comment: well, when you make ng new ClientApp, you have yet the correct angular.json. You must change your angular 2 app to set angular 6. Just be carefully with Rxjs (change all the old map,shitchMap,etc  using pipe https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax. If you use an old bootstrap.css, you must choose change your .html or replace the bootstrap.css 4.0 to your bootstrap.css. Then you compare your old startUp.cs with the new one and add carefully the new services and configuration. Sorry, I don't know a sortcut :(

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work either. Even if I create a new project, And I update the packages, I still get the same error.

Comment: I have made this new project available on github https://github.com/dobrinsky/Marksal-open.git Please some help @Eliseo . this is really hard to get by

Comment: I don't know if your problem is in the angular or in the .NET Core 2.1. I try to explain in steps what I make to create an .NET Core 2.1 and Angular 6 application, but all the add to your stratUp.cs you must make one to one and check if some change

Answer (score 1):

steps to have an aplication using .NET Core 2.1 API and Angular 6

1.-create a new proyect Aplication web ASP.NET Core -->choose Angular https enabled

2.-close the project

3.-make a copy ClientApp src to another folder

4.-remove ClientApp folder

5.-in folder of the app (where is startup.cs) write

```
ng new ClientApp
```

see my version is Angular CLI:6.1.3 Node 10.5.0 OS:win32 x64

6.-Open the project and ejecute in IISExpress (ask you about the https,
    don't worry add security exception of your navigator)

7.-You see in localhost:##### the aplication

8.-Copy the folder src saved before

9.-Goto to ClientApp folder and add bootstrap-css only

```
 npm install bootstrap-css-only
```

10.-in angular.json, you must include the .css in "styles" so your angular.json becomes like

```
 ...
             "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
...
```

11.-You can instal if you want ng-bootstrap (in ClientApp folder)

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

And in app.module.ts add the import

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

and add NgbModule, in imports like show it in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

12.-Finally replace nav-manu.component.html with the code

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }'>
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/"]'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' >
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/counter"]' >Counter</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' >
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/fetch-data"]' >Fech Data</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Yet we have an API aplication using angular 6

see in https://github.com/EliseoPlunker/sample-.NET-Core-2.1-Angular-6

Answer (score 0):

The error had nothing to do with C#

It was an Angular problem.

For some reason, Angular didn't told anything about some compilation errors. Visual Studio didn't show any errors and there were no errors in the browser's console and there were no errors in Output -> ASP.NET Core Web server (though sometimes they appear).

I took Eliseo's advice to create the project from scratch and actually adding one element at a time. There was no indication of this, but in some services, there was this import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

I know that map is not used anymore, but I think that this should be shown as an error in the compilation.

After removing this error and others, it worked.

I believed it was a C# because it was the only indication of an error that I got.

Comment: NOT import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'. MUST be import {map} from ''rxjs/operators'. The things change from Rxjs 5 to Rxjs 6. see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md