# Problems building .Net Core Angular application in TFS webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed error

Tags: .net, angular, tfs, .net-core, build-templates

I have created an Angular project based on the built-in Angular template present in the Visual 2017 .net Core.

I have no problems buinding runninng it locally in IIS.

However when trying to publish the project to the local IIS (or externally using TFS build definition) I get the following errors:

```
PublishRunWebpack:
npm install
  npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@6.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.7.2 <2.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@6.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 || ~2.8.0 || ~2.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN aspnet-webpack@3.0.0 requires a peer of webpack-dev-middleware@^1.8.4 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN awesome-typescript-loader@5.2.0 requires a peer of typescript@^2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN tsickle@0.32.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.10 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

  audited 11354 packages in 9.846s
  found 0 vulnerabilities

  node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod
  D:\BuildAgent1\_work\67\s\AngTempProj\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:244
                throw err;
                ^

EXEC(0,0): Error : webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.
EXEC : error : webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead. [D:\BuildAgent1\_work\67\s\AngTempProj.csproj]
```

...then:

```
AngTempProj.csproj(49,5): Error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" exited with code 1.
D:\BuildAgent1\_work\67\s\AngTempProj.csproj(49,5): error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" exited with code 1.
Done Building Project "D:\BuildAgent1\_work\67\s\AngTempProj.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "D:\BuildAgent1\_work\67\s\AngTempProj.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
```

...and finally:

```
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

To be honest I don't know how to configure the webpack.config.vendor.js which is triggered by the commands embedded in the .proj file:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">

    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->

    <Exec Command="npm install" />

    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />

    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />
```

This is what my webpack.config.vendor.js looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    "@angular/material",
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
                // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
                /@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/,
                path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')
            ), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

And yes I realise I should have separate config files for DEV and PRD. 
I know I'm doing something wrong but I'm new to Angular etc

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not use Angular 6? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440735/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-the-specified-file-file-name/52487704#52487704

Comment: VS 2017 .NET Core is shippeed with the Angular template (version 4.2.5) which I have upgraded to the latest Angular 6 version.

Comment: update the SPA, the version of the new template is the Angular 5 in Core.NET 2.1. I think that you can upgrade using: dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates (the things are easer)

Comment: The .NET Core Angular SPA was upgraded following the this document: 
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/ (except all the angular stuff was brought the latest version 6)
and it is all workign fine. The problem seems to be related to the uglifier during the publish process in the prod mode. 

Heres my

Comment: Heres my package.json webpack contents... Maybe you can spot discrepencies:
{....
    "webpack": "4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.3",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a bit of reading/searching it turned out Webpack > 4 doesn't require the UglifyJsPlugin so simply removing references from both webpack.config and webpack.config.vendor files fixed the issue.