# Convert existing asp.net core 2.1 angular app to Angular 6 and Angular CLI 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I created an asp.net core 2.1 angular web app which is come with 5.2 Angular. I would like to upgrade to angular 6 and Angular CLI 6.
These are the steps I did:

1. Create project in VS2017 .net 2.1 Angular
2. npm install
3. ng update --all
4. ng update @angular/cli
5. create angular.json
6. added "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0", to dev dependencies
7. npm install
8. ng build --prod (this threw error say "Unknown option: --extractCss"
9. removed --extractCss from package.json
10. Run application from VS2017. Application loads up but css is not loading
11. when I try to deploy to azure web app application does not load.

Not sure what other steps I am missing

Sample project link https://github.com/tkumark/WebApplication3

[image]

Comment: check angular's official update guide https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Personally I would create a new Angular 6 app with the CLI and manually copy over the pieces of your Angular app. Might sound like a lot but will be worth it. Keep your API and frontend in separate projects.

Comment: @AdrianBrand is there a asp.net core 2.1 Angular 6 template I can work off

Comment: I would not use the Visual Studio templates, I would separate my .NET API and my Angular CLI projects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440735/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-the-specified-file-file-name/52487704#52487704 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your *angular.json* to force **extractCss** on build and don't miss to add **bootstrap** as style dependency:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "extractCss": true,
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```

Check the *configuration* section as well:

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
...
              "extractCss": true
            "debug": {
...
```

The **angular.json** schema can be found here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace

You also need to check if the SPA static files root path match the out path of your **angular.json**:

**Startup.cs**

```
// In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
```

**angular.json**

```
"outputPath": "dist",
```

Comment: I tried that but seems to make no difference Here is my sample code which I am trying to upgrade. https://github.com/tkumark/WebApplication3

Comment: in **.angular.json** the output dir was: `"outDir": "dist"` in the **angular.json** the out path is :`"outputPath": "dist/WebApplication3"` try to set it to `dist`

Comment: I updated the to "outputPath": "dist" but did not see any change

Comment: Can you share the build output ?

Comment: bootstrap is missing in styles section of your **angular.json**, I updated the answer